# Is there a documentation of Blender's installer's command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, windows, installation, documentation

I only found [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) of CLI for Blender itself. What about the installer? I can't find any sort of info anywhere, I also asked few times in the support chat with no reply.

Why do I need it? Main goal would be to change the installer to install only one version when upgrading, if possible. But I'd like to see what's possible in general, for automatic installation with Chocolatey.

Comment: "*Change the installer to install only one version*" How many versions is your installer deploying? There is no official Chocolatey installation that I'm aware of

Comment: This https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/blender installs at the very least 2 versions, 3.5 and 3.6, but I think I'm pretty sure it's "infinite" for all minor versions. But I remember reading somewhere it's default behavior of Blender isntaller in general, not just the Chocolatey's one. I also clarified it happens when upgrading.

Comment: Official installers only install the one single version you downloaded. Chocolatey installers are provided by third party, so official documentation doesn't cover using them. You will have to ask their authors for assistance, this is not something we can help you with, and this question seems off topic here.

Comment: It's 100% not off-topic. I'm asking for the official installer's CLI documentation. Chocolatey install just downloads and executes that...

Comment: This is the whole PowerShell that gets ran: https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-packages/blob/master/automatic/blender/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1 There's nothing except running the installer. So sorry, but you're not correct about this being not the default behavior of silent Blender install with just `/quiet /norestart` args. Also, even if it was, I'm not asking about Chocolatey primarily. This is only a side topic that serves as an example, the main question asks about CLI arguments documentation for official installer.

Comment: As far as I know there is no CLI for the installer, the documentation mentions none. The Chocolatey installer is doing something else in the background then, because Blender installers are lean and include a single version only to my knowledge. If you want custom installation behavior you are better off downloading a zip file and scripting the behavior yourself from Powershell, Python or Batch

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if you have more than one blender version installed it is likely because you didnt uninstall the previous one

Comment: It's really not. The question asks about **documentation for installer CLI** that I couldn't find, anything else is an example. If the answer is - "no" - that's fine. But please don't close for one of many possible use cases. I also just confirmed this has nothing to do with Chocolatey - installer downlaoded from official website by default installs to `C:\Program FIles\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6`. Which is of course different for each version. I know I can uninstall old versions, but I'm looking for various options for automation, not only for possibility of installing a single version.

Comment: On Windows there are only three official channels to install Blender: Blender.org which proposes either an executable installer or a zip file, or Steam, or Microsoft Store. There are no other official ways, hence no "official CLI installer" to document. Other channels to install and upgrade

Comment: When it comes to chocolatey, AFAIK you either install one version via `choco install blender <optional --version=x.x.x>` or you upgrade via `choco upgrade blender <optional --version=x.x.x>`. Using the `Install` command should always install what you asked (specific asked version or latest available) no matter what you already have installed. While upgrade should upgrade your latest version to the new one. Some people like to manually uninstall and then instal instead of using upgrade. You can use `choco uninstall blender --all-versions` to clear all potential versions you might have.

Comment: @L0Lock `choco upgrade`  installs new versions separately though, as if you run the official executable installer that you mentioned with mentioned flags (or if you click through its GUI without changing anything), the new version goes to a separate folder. But I see the answer is just "none exists" then and the only available installer CLI flags are whatever is included by default in WiX Toolset, which seems to be the used installer.